# Issue: AWS POST File using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am having problem with my nodejs code which integrates with AWS.

```
        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'ap-southeast-1',
            accessKeyId: '<ACCESSKEY>',
            secretAccessKey: '<SECRET-KEY>',
        });

        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(req.file);
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'gimo-store',
            Key: 'cat.jpg', // File name you want to save as in S3
            Body: fileContent
        };

        s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
        });
```

I'm getting the error below

The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object

Please help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong in the code. Make sure `req.file` is not undefined. When it is undefined, thats when you get this error.

Also, you could use promise version of upload instead of callback like this

```
s3.upload(params).promise().then(data => console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`));
```